# fuse-python xmp.py - Not able to create a file

Tags: python, filesystems, fuse

I am writing a Network File System, and I have started by trying to understand the xmp.py provided with python-fuse.

Well basically I'm sending all the calls over the network, executing it on the server-side and sending the result to the client and returning it to the user. These parts are working perfectly fine.

The problem I am facing is that, the xmp.py is not able to create a file and hence the problem is showing up in my Network File System too.

The steps I have followed are:

1. Installed fuse-python by:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-fuse
   ```
2. Then I go into the directory where `xmp.py` is located:

   ```
   cd /usr/share/doc/python-fuse/examples/
   ```
3. I ran the xmp.py program with the following command-line arguments

   ```
   python xmp.py -o root=/home/user /tmp/fuse
   ```

   where `/home/user` will be replicated or mounted on `/tmp/fuse`
4. Then I cd into the `/tmp/fuse` directory and try to make a file with `cat`, like:

   ```
   cd /tmp/fuse
   cat > temp.txt
   ```

   I get the error

   ```
   bash: temp.txt: Invalid argument
   ```

After a lot of poking around, I believe that this is due to the function

```
def getattr(self, path):
    return os.lstat("." + path)
```

When I do a `cat > temp.txt`, `os.lstat("./temp.txt")` is called and an error is thrown as the file `/home/user/temp.txt` is not found. After this the program gets stuck for a while and slows down my computer.

Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think i have figured it out, the problem that i saw was once `os.lstat("./temp.txt")` fails, the file class's `__init__` method is called and then immediately truncate is called and the program returns.

One solution that i followed was to not use the file class at all, and to implement the Fuse class' `open`/`create` to make the file.

This approach worked for me. If anyone has a better suggestion please let me know. I would like to use the object-oriented approach and use the file class.